# prestashop custom calculation add to base price

Tags: prestashop

please can someone give me a hint how to create custom price calculation programaticaly? Need to add calculated price to base price and show properly in cart with additional item text

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need SpecificPrice model or API method.
You can get some documentation in https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/tutorials/advanced-use/specific-price/
Read this carefully, sadly Prestashop gives very few info (for free, at least).